# How to view data in a specific row number of a CSV file with Powershell

Tags: csv, powershell, ssis

As the title states - I need a script that allows me to enter a CSV filename and an associated row number which when executed displays that data in that row number of the specified CSV file.

Context: I have an SSIS packet that imports transaction records that I download from another company into SQL every day. The file is in CSV format and when there is an issue with the data in a row I get a truncation error stating that it occurred on (X) row.

The csv files are very large and  opening them in Excel isn't a possibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(Import-csv filename.csv)[9]
```

This will find the 10th record (it is a zero indexed array, so the first item is number 0, not 1)

Import-Csv will parse every record in the file, so depending on the size of the "very large" file, you may need other solutions.

If you just want to see the row unparced

```
(Get-content filename.csv)[9]
```

Again, this is zero indexed.

Comment: Unfortuantely this took extremely long for my "very large" (7 mill row) file.  
After searching longer than I'd like to admit I found another solution that worked for efficiently for my circumstances (pardon the horrible formatting as I'm clearly lost on how to do anything in this comment field) Thank you for your help!  
---  
Get-Content filename.csv | Select -Index 9